# Xcode - library project with file template asset

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm creating a library project in xcode. The library will rely heavily on a specific pattern for which I've created a file template. This works fine when I copy the template catalog to the "File Templates" catalog.

**The question is:** 
Can I add this template to my library project? The way I imagine it the file template would automagically be added to xcode when user drags my library project into his/hers project.